# How can I use a service account to get the email of a user in a Google Apps domain, without already knowing an email from that domain?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to use a Service Account to access data of a domain that's installed my app (via Google Apps Marketplace).

But calls to the Google Admin SDK api, to get lists of users or lists of admins for a given domain, seem to require that you know the email address of a user in the domain.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object

```
  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
  .setTransport(httpTransport)
  .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
  .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
  .setServiceAccountScopes(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USERS)
  .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
      new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
  .build();
  Directory service = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
  .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

  Directory.Users.List request = service.users().list().setDomain(domain);
```

The above works, but requires that you called the `setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)` method on the builder.  Without that, when you execute the request, you'll get a 403 "not authorized for this resource/api error".  This is documented by several existing questions, such as [Google Apps Admin API: need to specify account user for service account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305915/google-apps-admin-api-need-to-specify-account-user-for-service-account) .

But how do you know a `userEmail` in the first place? You can't get a list of emails in the domain without already knowing an email in the domain.  You *could* store the email of the admin who first installs the app - but this seems improper and is insufficient. What if this admin's account is deleted or the email address changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service accounts cannot be granted admin rights on the domain; they must impersonate a domain admin, hence the need for an email address. The recommended approach is to store the email of the admin that installed the app, or have a configuration screen where they can set the email of the admin account to use. As you've pointed out this approach can be a little fragile, if the admin account is deleted or it's email changes. Make sure you handle that case, by disabling the app and alerting the user that an admin must re-configure it.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  Your answer makes it clear what must be done under the current constraints. But it's not very elegant UX.  I still think Google should provide some way to legitimately access API resources as an app, rather than as a user.

Comment: And how do i find that stored admin for target domain when some other user visits the application? By domain from email address? What if the case is: admin of primary domain installs the application, and user from secondary domain (same google apps customer(Id)) visits - there is no domain match and customerId attribute is not visible for non-admins.

Comment: You can use the Admin SDK Directory API to lookup the customer ID for a given user, and use that as a primary key instead of domain name.